# r: sym() function failing [can't convert string to symbol]

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation, r-mice

I have a dataset with over 10 categorical variables and about 20 numerical ones. I'm trying to edit Stef van Buuren's `mice.impute.logreg` function which is available on [github](https://github.com/stefvanbuuren/mice/blob/master/R/mice.impute.logreg.R), to call `glm.fit()`, but with a higher `maxit` value to try to reach convergence. However, on running the code as is, I get the following error:

```
Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols
```

and it comes from this line in the code:

```
 rv <- t(chol(sym(fit.sum$cov.unscaled)))
```

I went ahead to print out the content of `fit.sum$cov.unscaled`, and got a huge covariance matrix(?) with all variables (categorical ones kinda one-hot-encoded(?)), something like this, but way larger:

```
              Proteinuria22 Proteinuria23 Proteinuria24 Proteinuria25      Aetiol22      Aetiol23      Aetiol24
              -0.0775687218  6.603074e-02  6.995692e-01 -1.0462947407 -1.990400e-01 -3.756997e+01 -6.198267e-01
Weight2       -0.0003022753  6.802872e-04 -1.138967e-03 -0.0043737786  2.550278e-04  3.380858e-02  6.343819e-04
Height2        0.0174235854 -8.945169e-02 -2.588742e-01  0.2947104430 -1.763788e-01  2.027542e+00 -3.676413e-02
BMI22          0.0038176385 -2.246294e-02  3.529623e-02  0.0507158023 -1.959203e-03  1.515110e+00  3.618223e-02
BMI23          0.0463573025  4.600740e-02  1.210799e-01  0.1009359117  6.368376e-03  7.268413e-01 -4.677462e-03
BMI24          0.0230542190  4.822956e-02  1.424563e-01  0.2136974371 -7.688207e-02 -4.099045e+00 -4.920604e-02
Proteinuria21  0.2564365948  2.399999e-01  2.869407e-01  0.2866854741 -3.345524e-02  7.021764e+00 -1.380307e-02
Proteinuria22  0.5114421153  2.658057e-01  2.444392e-01  0.2575295706 -5.555202e-02  2.132465e+00 -2.367527e-02
Proteinuria23  0.2658056994  8.278569e-01  2.805812e-01  0.1743841777 -5.433797e-02 -5.289189e+00 -1.905688e-02
Proteinuria24  0.2444391680  2.805812e-01  5.436426e-01  0.2272864202 -4.551615e-02  2.533664e+00 -1.962130e-02
Proteinuria25  0.2575295706  1.743842e-01  2.272864e-01  1.1656567100 -7.355628e-02  9.412580e+00 -1.330318e-01
Aetiol22      -0.0555520221 -5.433797e-02 -4.551615e-02 -0.0735562813  4.327236e-01  4.698377e+00  1.196196e-01
Aetiol23       2.1324651321 -5.289189e+00  2.533664e+00  9.4125804535  4.698377e+00  1.175992e+04  2.984111e+00
```

Since I'm still not very conversant with `r`, I really have no idea what this means... I understand that `sym()` is used to convert a string to a symbol, but I don't understand how (or why) such a huge matrix would be converted into a symbol. Any ideas, please?

Comment: I think you need to convert the column name string into `sym`. Not clear why you need `sym` here

Comment: Thanks, @akrun, but could you please be more elaborate? I don't really catch your meaning.

Comment: I meant `sym("cov.unscaled")` and then evaluate (`!!`) within the tidyverse environment

Comment: Okay... But it's actually `fit.sum$cov.unscaled`, and when I try to do `sym("fit.sum$cov.unscaled")`, (assuming that's meant to be a column name...?) I get another error: `Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
  cannot coerce type 'symbol' to vector of type 'any'`. I believe that's coming from the surrounding `chol` function...

Comment: @akrun Oh, thanks. I got your meaning, now, when I checked out the `chol` function. I just removed the `sym` function, and the code works. I have no idea why it was put in the code in the first place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to pointers from @arun's comment, I discovered that I only needed to remove the `sym()` function, given the use of the surrounding `chol` [function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/chol):

> Compute the Choleski factorization of a real symmetric positive-definite square matrix.

I'm yet to figure out why the code author put the `sym()` function there in the first place, though, since the code apparently breaks with it, but works fine without it.